# Recently I've been working on Chaquopy and there I've tried to implement port scanner in android using Python-Nmap Library

Tags: python, android, kotlin, chaquopy

**Error:** PortScannerError: 'nmap program was not found in path. PATH is : /product/bin:/apex/com.android.runtime/bin:/apex/com.android.art/bin:/system_ext/bin:/system/bin:/system/xbin:/odm/bin:/vendor/bin:/vendor/xbin'

I've also tried to implement several other libraries like pandas, cryptography, numpy etc... but these libraries seems to work perfectly fine.

Is python-nmap a plateform dependent library??

Is there any other alternate way to use nmap in my android Studio project??

Link to my Project: https://github.com/Tejas-Tripathi/Chaoupy

Please let me know, Thanks for your Answers

Comment: Please post your code here in the question, formatted as code (use the `{}` button), not as a link. The linked code can change (especially on github), making the question unusable for others with similar problems. Please see [ask]. Have you tried installing nmap? The [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/python-nmap/) says: "Now you may invoke nmap from python". Sounds pretty clear to me that you do need to install nmap.

Comment: Although python-nmap is a pure-Python library, it requires the nmap executable, which wouldn't be easy to use in an Android app. So I suggest you look for a self-contained Python port scanner library instead.

Comment: @Robert , Thanks for your suggestion from next time I'll try to ask nice question with proper format,

Comment: @mhsmith I got it bro, the thing is I've tried to install nmap executable using Inno Setup Extractor, but error remains the same, I think I've to install it in path specified in error but that's not possible as of now.

Currently I'm trying to implement it using socket library, lets hope for the best